# Employee Manager relationship SQLITE DJANGO

Tags: django, sqlite, relationship

I am honestly struggling trying to understand how i can start off an employee to manager relationship.

I've read a few things about LEFT, OUTER and INNER joins. I am using SQLite3 and django framework

background:
i have a **user** table, this contains information about the user.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  editable=False)
    bio = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='', blank=True )
    department = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='', blank=True)
    team = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='', blank=True)
    jobrole = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=job_role)
```

My end goal, is that I would like to be able to have multiple managers to multiple users. Should i just add "reports_to" to the profile class, and then create a separate table that relates to the user-id and has a manager-id?

so on the profile page, you can see who the user's manager is, and the manager can log into his profile and see who their employees are (multiple list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should i just add `reports_to` to the profile class, and then create a separate table that relates to the user-id and has a manager-id?

This is indeed how you implement a *many-to-many relation* in a relational database: with a [*junction table* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table). But Django can automatically create such table. If you work with a [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField), Django will automatically create the junction table:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # …
    reports_to = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        related_name='inferiors',
        symmetrical=False
    )
```